# How to verify oauth signature or request?

Tags: api, oauth, restful-authentication

The client is using oauth signing their request and call my server, I know the client's oauth key and secret, then how can I verify the call is from the actual user? should I calculate the signature with all parameters sent along with the request and compare it with the signature within the request? I am using singpost library.

Thank you, any hint will be very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

OK for the future reference - to validate the signature, this is what I did:

> Parse all parameters in the incoming request's header and use all these parameters and my own consumer credential to calculate the signature again, then compare with the incoming signature. It's a pain for me since no proper library can do it in a easy way, I have to write it myself...

Comment: How did you manage? I am using signpost as well, but even when I sign the same URL string twice, the signatures come out different:

Comment: I know this is an old post but any chance you still have/can share the solution of how you managed to verify and compare signatures?